# User restrictions on views based on customer user properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3.

I would like to create an action filter to determine if a user can access a view.  I have a User class with properties like IsAdministrator, IsTrusteeUser and IsAuditUser.  How would I create an action filter to block certain users if the don't belong in some of these roles?

And aslo how would I use this in my views to hide/display certain controls?  I would appreciated some code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why re-invent the wheel?

Put the `[Authorize]` action filter on the action/controller, specifying the role required:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public ActionResult SomeAdminPage() { // }
```

Either that, or you could implement your own custom authorization filter by implementing `IAuthorizationFilter`.

Comment: I'm not using any type of membership, I just have a table that says whether a user is an administrator user, audit user, etc.  So do you think I must create a custom authorization filter?

Comment: @Brendan - right, my bad - if your not using the built in Role Provider (which is seperate to Membership, afaik) - you might need a custom authorization filter.

Comment: Just a quick question.  I have a table with users in it (staff numbers) and my own tables with the roles in them.  Can the role membership be used?  How would I implement it into my current system?

Comment: @Brendan Vogt - that's not a quick question. :) Essentially, you'll be creating your own SqlMembershipProvider and SqlRoleProvider - and update your web.config to add your providers there. There's a good series on memberships/roles/profiles on 4guysfromrolla - http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx. But the answer is yes - it can be used, many have done before.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can implement IActionFilter interface for writing such an attribute extension for Users access permissions checking, a little about coding you can find on 
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4971447/405673)
2. To hide/display certain controls on UI, it is not the work of  ActionFilters, rather you should either make separate views for each user and redirect him accordingly or do some

> If/else

to acheive this.