# Tell in an ActionFilterAttribute whether this is a redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionfilterattribute

I am trying to create an ActionFilterAttribute that runs only once per request, so I am doing something like this.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
        return;

    // More stuff here
}
```

I might need to check that `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()` is also false in some cases, but my real problem is how to tell that it is not a redirect. When action `X` redirects to action `Y`, then the filter runs twice once for `X` and once for `Y` (the `IsChildAction` is false for `Y`).

I tried to save some key on `filterContext.HttpContext.Items`, that will tell me that the filter has already run, but these items are not shared between `X` and `Y`.

Any ideas how I can tell from the `ActionExecutingContext` that this is a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this is what you are looking for:

[Using an MVC Action Filter to catch redirects in Ajax requests and return a JsonResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971447/using-an-mvc-action-filter-to-catch-redirects-in-ajax-requests-and-return-a-json)

You can check if it is a redirect result or a redirect to route result

```
var redirectResult = filterContext.Result as RedirectResult;
    if (filterContext.Result is RedirectResult)
    {
        // It was a RedirectResult => do something
    }
    else if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
    {
        // It was a RedirectToRouteResult => do something

    }
```

Comment: The purpose of my filter is to block the action if some conditions are met. I need a solution for OnActionExecuting rather than OnActionExecuted.